# Microsoft Teams Client Credentials Flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, microsoft-teams

Wondering if it is possible to use the client credentials flow for authorization when developing a Microsoft Teams Tab Application.

I see general Active Directory information for the flow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds), does this apply to teams apps?

If not, how would one recommend completing authorization while E2E testing the app?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "Microsoft Teams app"? Are you looking to leverage the APIs exposed through Graph? Build a Bot? Add a custom Tab? A little more information would be super helpful.

Comment: Marc - indeed. It's a Teams Tab. Authorizing Office365. I suppose following these directions would work, then? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/building-service-apps-in-office-365

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Using `client_credentials` requires some special consent from an Admin on the tenant and it doesn't authenticate an actual user. You could use this flow to make Microsoft Graph calls from within your app but it wouldn't be aware of the current user.

The documentation ([Authenticate a user in your Microsoft Teams tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication)) is assuming you want to authenticate the current Teams User. Since `client_credentials` doesn't involve interacting with the user this doesn't really concern Teams itself. It is simply something you'd implement on your own as part of your application.

If you're specifically asking about using `client_credentials` with `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate` then no. If you're app is using Client Credentials then there isn't a pop-up in your workflow. You're authentication is happening at the application level and would need to be configured/authorized prior to deploying the app to actual users.